# SQL SELECT From two tables (friendship) statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the following tables created:

Table #1: tbl_Connections

```
USE [taaraf_db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Connections](
    [uc_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [uc_User] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [uc_Connection] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [uc_IsPending] [int] NOT NULL,
    [uc_DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Connections] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [uc_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Connections] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_Connections_uc_IsPending]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [uc_IsPending]
GO
```

Table #2: tbl_LiveStream

```
USE [taaraf_db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_LiveStreams](
    [ls_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ls_Story] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ls_User] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ls_Connection] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ls_DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_LiveStreams] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ls_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Now uc_User in tbl_Connections represents the user who initiated a friend request, and uc_Connection
represents the other party.
Same concept is applied on the second table (tbl_LiveStreams)

I am trying to select all new LiveStreams for a cetrain user, LiveStream should be retrieved for a specific user only if that user is connected to the other party (uc_IsPending = 0)

I have a C# function that takes the following arguments:

> ```
> public static DataTable GetAsyncLiveStream(string CurrentUser, int startAt, int howMany) { ... }
> ```

And with the above, a DataTable should return all new items in LiveStream for the given CurrentUser (ls_User) if the requirements specified above are true.

This is sort of like the Facebook news feed, what's happening with friends etc...
Oh yeah, tbl_LiveStream is populated whenever someone (ls_User) initates some sort of specific event to (ls_Connection).

I'm not sure if i'm complicating my life here but that's what I have and all help is appreciated.

I should mention that I've done this by looping through all returned records from tbl_LiveStream and done some validation using a custom class function .IsFriends() that will go and check for friendship status in the database and programatically populates a DataTable... Which is sort of stupid, I admit. But I'm not sure how to do this.

One last thing,
I'm using the following query to return limited results:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ) AS rownum, ls_Id
FROM )
AS A
WHERE A.rownum BETWEEN (@start) AND (@start + @rowsperpage)
```

Please help and thank you for your time.

**EDIT**
I'd like to note that this is how I am fetching who's friends with who from the tbl_Connections Table.

```
    const string sql = "SELECT REPLACE((uc_Connection + uc_User), @CurrentUser, '') AS Connection " +
                       "FROM tbl_Connections Connection " +
                       "WHERE (@CurrentUser = uc_Connection) OR (@CurrentUser = uc_User)";
```

Comment: You should be defining a view for this, that your `row_number()` wrapper query uses.  What do you have so far?

Comment: I have what I posted above... That's about it for now. I really don't know how to start.

Comment: Are you able to modify the database?  What are your actual requirements (If you have two different tables with [effectively] the _exact_ same structure, you likely have a table to pull out)?  You should be using prepared statements, not concatenated strings, if you aren't already (SQL Injection).  Table names should _not_ be prefixed with `tbl` (meaningless, if _everything_ is prefixed), and columns should not be prefixed with shortened table names (confusing, pointless when only selecting from one table, and you want to alias when selecting from multiple tables anyways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ) AS rownum, ls_Id
FROM )
AS A
WHERE A.rownum BETWEEN (@start) AND (@start + @rowsperpage)
```

This syntax is wrong. You can't do it like that. Use a Union, or use LINQ to SQL.

From a critique perspective, don't get DataTables, get Entities. You seem to be over complicating quite a bit here, with technologies you may not be familiar with. I'd advise taking all currently existing data and dumping it to a CSV file, then starting the application from scratch with something like [Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/), which can abstract away some of these details for you.