# SQL Friends (Connections) JOIN Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, select

```
tbl_Connections:

uc_Id   uc_User uc_Connection   uc_IsPending    uc_DateTime
72  jasonramia  jeffreyramia    0   2011-10-29 16:42:49.000
74  jasonramia  beta    0   2011-10-29 16:55:38.000
75  jeffreyramia    beta    0   2011-10-29 20:36:11.000

tbl_LiveStream:

ls_Id   ls_Story    ls_User ls_Connection   ls_DateTime
30  test    jeffreyramia    jasonramia  2011-10-29 19:16:48.000
31  aheln   jasonramia  jasonramia  2011-10-29 19:17:48.000
32  test    jasonramia  beta    2011-10-29 19:27:02.000
```

I need to return * from LiveStream for jeffreyramia (or any other user) only if ls_User or ls_Connection is friends is conncted to jeffreyramia from table tbl_Connections (uc_User or uc_Connection)

More details here: [SQL SELECT From two tables (friendship) statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955971/sql-select-from-two-tables-friendship-statement)

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Nothing yet as I have no clue on how to do this... :/

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). This should get close.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Connections AS connect 
INNER JOIN
tbl_LiveStream AS live
WHERE connect.us_User = live.ls_User
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Connections AS connect 
INNER JOIN
tbl_LiveStream AS live
WHERE connect.us_User = live.ls_Connection
```

You could also use LINQ to SQL if you have C# available with classes that encapsulate these tables, but you haven't shown a lot of detail here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've posted more info on this page here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955971/sql-select-from-two-tables-friendship-statement i'm getting this error when executing the query Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. ln5 and 11

Comment: @JeffreyRamia: Replacing `WHERE` (both) with `ON` should eliminate *that* error (but might uncover another one).